# Core Data: Using Predicates with to-many Relationship

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest

To-Many relationship in Entity "Meetings" <--->> "Users"

I made a NSManagedSubclass for "Meetings" and it has a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *users;
```

Objects in *users save fine and I can see them.  But when I try to fetch, nothing happens.    I have the breakpoint setup inside the Block and it seems like the fetch Block never reaches the breakpoint.  No errors.  Applications is still running.

I have the following code:

```
        NSString *userName = @"iphone";
        NSLog(@"Username %@", userName);

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Meeting"];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"users.username == %@", userName];
        NSLog(@"Predicate %@", predicate);
        [request setPredicate:predicate];

        [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request onSuccess:^(NSArray *results)
         { // I have setup the breakpoint here 
             NSLog(@"results.count %i", results.count);

             if(results.count > 0)
             {
                 NSLog(@"object found");
             }
         }onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"There was an error! %@", error);
         }];
```

Log:

```
2013-10-12 20:10:19.200 App[3128:c07] Username iphone
2013-10-12 20:10:19.200 App[3128:c07] Predicate users.username == "iphone"
```

I can fetch for other attributes in Meetings just fine.  i.e.  If I replace the predicate line with :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"meetings_id == %@", meetings_id];
```

And the breakpoint will stop the code, the will show "object found".

Again, I can see the "iphone" user inside the users relationship.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it because its in a block ?

Comment: What do you mean?  Block works fine with other attributes.

Answer (score 3):

For to-many relationships you have to use a predicate modifier, that states what is the intended behaviour. Since you are searching for `Meeting`s, CoreData cannot figure out from your predicate `users.username == %@`, if you want `Meeting`s where `ALL` users have the specified username or only those where `ANY` single user meets the requirements (see here for in-depth [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW3)).

Try this for a change, since I think it is what you would want:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY users.username == %@", userName]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm getting the same behavior.  My log reads:2013-10-12 20:38:34.367 App[3532:c07] Username iphone
2013-10-12 20:38:34.367 App[3532:c07] Predicate ANY users.username == "iphone"

Comment: Is there  a way to get all display all the objects in users?